# How to render a table with some fixed and some dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to get a table with these columns:

- [Name]
- [Club]
- [Dynamic1]
- [Dynamic2]
- [Dynamic3]
- etc etc.

I tried this:

```html
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'rowTmpl', foreach: runners }">
    </tbody>
</table>
<script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr data-bind="template: { name: 'colTmpl', foreach: radios }" >
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: club"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script id="colTmpl" type="text/html">
        <td>aa</td>
</script>
@section Scripts{
    <script src="/Scripts/knockout-1.3.0beta.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vm = {
            id: 1,
            name: 'H21',
            radios: ['2km', '4km', 'mål'],
            runners: ko.observableArray([
                { name: 'Mikael Eliasson', club: 'Göteborg-Majorna OK', radios: ko.observableArray([{}, {}, {}]) },
                { name: 'Ola Martner', club: 'Göteborg-Majorna OK', radios: ko.observableArray([{}, {}, {}]) }
            ])
        };

        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    </script>
}
```

My problem is that the tds inside `colTmpl` is not databoud, it's empty and placed after the third column with the text 'aa'. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSzvn/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using [1.3 beta](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/) (your fiddle is referencing the latest build), then you can do this:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: runners">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: club"></td>
            <!-- ko foreach: radios-->
            <td>aa</td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bd7DT/

If you need to do this prior to 1.3 with jQuery templates, then you would want to pass the first item in your array into the template via [templateOptions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_6_passing_additional_data_to_your_template_using_) and do an `{{if}}` to check if you are on the first radio and render the two cells.  Another option in jQuery templates is to use `{{each}}` around your dynamic cells rather than the `foreach` option of the template binding on the parent.  You would lose some efficiency, if your columns are frequently changing dynamically.  I can provide a sample for these two options, if necessary.

Comment: That something I hadn't picked up yet from 1.3, much better than I came up with.

Comment: Thanks! That is awesome, and yeah I'm using 1.3 beta.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the fact that the content of `<tr data-bind="template: { name: 'colTmpl', foreach: radios }" >` is getting replaced by the template you specify.

If you instead do:

```
<script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">
<tr> 
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: club"></td>
    <td data-bind="template: { name: 'colTmpl', foreach: radios }" ></td>
</tr>
</script>
<script id="colTmpl" type="text/html">
    <span> . aa . </span>
</script>
```

It will render.