# Knockout.js - Dynamic columns but limit to a maximum of 5 for each row

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I found a similar question/answer here: [How to render a table with some fixed and some dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414332/knockout-how-to-render-a-table-with-some-fixed-and-some-dynamic-columns)

But it does not completely solve my problem. I am trying to figure out how I can limit the number of dynamic columns to 5 per row and if there are more than 5 items in the view model, make a new row and repeat for all groups of 5 in the array.

For example:

```
var vm = {
    item: { name: 'test1' },
    item: { name: 'test2' },
    item: { name: 'test3' },
    item: { name: 'test4' },
    item: { name: 'test5' },
    item: { name: 'test6' }
};
```

Give that model, how can I get this table?

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
      <td>test4</td>
      <td>test5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>test6</td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To handle a situation like this, I would probably push the logic into your view model, so that your view can remain simple.  So the idea would be to use a dependentObservable to represent your "rows".  Then, your view can just foreach through the rows and then foreach through the cells in your row.

Here is a sample that makes that number of columns an observable, so that it can be dynamically updated.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/9TN9W/

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray(),
    columnLength: ko.observable(5)  
};

//sample data
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    viewModel.items.push({ name: 'test' + i });  
}

//return an array of rows.  Each row is an array of items
viewModel.rows = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var result = [],
        colLength = parseInt(this.columnLength(), 10),
        row;


    //loop through items and push each item to a row array that gets pushed to the final result
    for (var i = 0, j = this.items().length; i < j; i++) {
        if (i % colLength === 0) {
            if (row) {
              result.push(row);     
            }
            row = [];
        }
        row.push(this.items()[i]);
    }

    //push the final row  
    if (row) {
        result.push(row);
    }

    return result;
}, viewModel);
```

Comment: Ah, that is perfect and I can live with those viewModel changes. I'll probably keep my viewModel emitted from the server the same while manipulating it the JavaScript to address this issue just as you have demonstrated. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: For anyone interested in a solution example here is what I finally ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/cmschick/hyHQW/                            In the end I just create the table dynamically. There's a lot going on in this example, sorting, binding, updating, dynamic columns that won't wrap the text, etc. but it may be helpful for someone.

Comment: For a presentation problem, I recommend using CSS approach. http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've been able to get to a solution is this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
            <tr data-bind="template: { name: 'rowTmpl', foreach: items}">

            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">

        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>

        <!-- ko if: (vm.items.indexOf($data) + 1) % 5 == 0 -->
        <td>new row html here</td>
        <!-- /ko --> 

</script>


vm = {

            items: ko.observableArray([
                { name: 'test1' }, 
                { name: 'test2' }, 
                { name: 'test3' }, 
                { name: 'test4' }, 
                { name: 'test5' }, 
                { name: 'test6' } 
            ])
        }

        ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

.. which outputs this:

| test1 | test2 | test3 | test4 | test5 | new row html here | test6 |

This inserts a new element on every 5th item. However, if I substitute `<td>new row html here</td>` with `</tr><tr>` the template engine throws an error. Maybe, some other SO-er can build on this and show how to output not strictly correct html.

Anyway, hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the help. That's pretty much as far as I could get too. It seems as though I would somehow need to call the $parent binding scope and change the template to push another tr... How the heck to do that is the problem. Hey Steve Sanderson, how can this or CAN this be done?  Thanks.