# Limit foreach loop knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have this knockout mapping my array retreived from the ajax call below.

```
function InvoiceViewModel(data) {
var self = this;

self.survey = data;

}
```

Ajax Call

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:43043/api/damage',
    type: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
    data: {
        orderNumber: num,
        category: cat
    },
    success:
           function (data) {
               var usingRoutData = document.URL;
               ko.applyBindings(new InvoiceViewModel(data));
           },

    error: function () {
        alert('failure');
    }

});
```

My Array

```
 var test = {
  Name: Blah,
  Attributes: [
               {Name: Test, Type: Photo, Year:1988},
               {Name: Test, Type: Photo, Year:1988},
               {Name: Test, Type: Photo, Year:1988}
              ]
            };
```

How I am binding my data

```
 <div id="invoiceBodyWrapper">
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'invoice-template', foreach: surveys }">
</div>
```

```
<div class="invoiceWrapper">
    </div>
    <div id="completePictureWrapper" data-bind="template: { name: 'photo-template',     foreach: new Array(Attributes) }"></div>

</div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="photo-template">
<!-- ko if: classification === 'photo' -->
<div id="pictureWrappers">
    <img class="img" data-bind="attr: { src: 'http://myimagepath/download/full/' +    $index()+1 }" />
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
 </script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/DamageInvoiceCreation.js"></script>
```

I need a way to limit my attributes foreach loop to only show 2 of the 3 attributes. I have only found a few things on how to do this and they seem very overly complicated. I cannot imagine there is not a simple way to do this in knockout.

Comment: There is no loop in your post. How are you binding to your view?

Comment: Have you seen [Knockout.js - Dynamic columns but limit to a maximum of 5 for each row](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7669946/580951)

Comment: @Romoku a lot to learn in that question, but there's definitely applicable code. Good link!

Comment: @EntryLevel 
use "array.slice(0, 1)" in your loop to get first 2 items! Just it, javascript!

Answer (score 8):

If you always have 3 attributes and you always only want to show 2 of them, you don't need to foreach them, exactly.

However, there is the special binding context variable `$index()`, which will let you do some basic hiding, although it wouldn't prevent rendering. Because $index is 0-based, the condition is `$index() < 2`. As Andrey points out in the comments, [`$index` is an observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), so you have to call it with parentheses as a method, or comparisons won't do what you expect (you'll be comparing an int against a function).

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: survey.Attributes">
    <li data-bind="visible: $index() < 2">
        Name: <span data-bind="text: Name"> </span><br/>
        Type: <span data-bind="text: Type"> </span><br/>
        Year: <span data-bind="text: Year"> </span><br/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you want a generic limiter on a foreach loop, you're right, it's not simple. You would have to make a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Another approach you could consider is pre-processing your data in the viewmodel. When you set `this.survey = data;`, you could remove any of the attributes you don't want to display at that point.

Edit: I see from your edit that you know about the `ko: if` psuedo-elements. I completely forgot about those, but you could easily use one to prevent rendering template items beyond a certain index. The `foreach` would still evaluate the observable, that should not have any kind of huge overhead by itself.

Comment: I think you mean `$index()`. `$index < 3` will always return false http://jsfiddle.net/aDahT/1087/

Comment: This is by far one of the nicest solutions to this problem, if you only want to show 2 attributes you should use < 2 [0 is also a number :)]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the "if" binding rather than the "visible"? The visible binding will still render the elements but just hide them so you could be cluttering up the DOM with unwanted items. A cleaner way may also be to use the knockout repeat plugin: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript arrays include the excellent `slice` method that should fill your need nicely:

```
template: { name: 'photo-template', foreach: Attributes.slice(0,2) }
```

But as @Patrick-M mentioned, you don't need a loop:

```
template: { name: 'photo-template', data: Attributes[0] }
template: { name: 'photo-template', data: Attributes[1] }
```

My [Repeat](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) binding includes an option for limiting the number of repetitions:

```
<div data-bind="repeat: { foreach: Attributes, count: 2 }"
      data-repeat-bind="template: { name: 'photo-template', data: $item() }">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create computed with limited array limit:

```js
var limited = ko.computed( function() {
   return Attributes.slice(0, limit);
});
```

Then all you have to do to foreach limited. You can even add somekind of "more" element:

```html
<!-- ko if: Attributes().length > limit -->
    <div class="more">...</div>          
<!--/ko-->
```

I hope it will be helpful for further generations ;)

Answer (score 1):

Put the .slice(0,1) to get first 2 items from your FOREACH data-bind array (model).

```
.slice(0,1)
```

Something like this

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: items().slice(0, 1) } -->
    <div>
        Your html here!
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Or if you prefer

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: people.slice(0, 1)">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

About slice() 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Answer (score 0):

you can limit a loop in this way:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   if(i>1){
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you add some context to this . Also it is not the whole array I would like to limit just the sub-array

Comment: Then do this just for the sub-array. replace data with data.Attributes

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by pushing a subset of the original array items to another array in my viewmodel, then binding to the subset array.

Comment: I think sometimes people get "too ambitious" with KO, and throw too much JS in the HTML. This is a pretty logical solution. Don't get me wrong there is nothing wrong with KO, it's a great UI lib.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in a foreach is to use the $index

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: Attributes, as: 'item' } -->
<!-- ko if: $index() < 2 -->
<span class="item" data-bind="text:item.name"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try as below:

```
 <!-- ko foreach: { data: attributes, as: 'item' } -->
    <!-- ko if: $index() < 2 -->
    <span class="item" data-bind="text:item.name"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Example :

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: listItems">
                <li data-bind="attr: {id: id} ">
                  <a href="#" data-bind="text: label"></a>
                </li>
 </ul>
```