# How to set table cells dynamically using knockout foreach method?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a viewModel and a ko.observableArray given below

```
 users: ko.observableArray([{
     name: 'Name1',
     email: 'Email1'

 },
 {
     name: 'Name2',
     email: 'Email2'
 },
 {
      name: 'Name3',
     email: 'Email3'
 },
 {
     name: 'Name4',
     email: 'Email4'
 },
 {
     name: 'Name5',
     email: 'Email5'
 },
 {
     name: 'Name6',
     email: 'Email6'
 }
])
```

};

I want to create a table dynamically using knockout binding from the ko.observableArray 'users'.
 The table structure is given below

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far to that end.. ?

Comment: Can you explain what this has to do specifically with `mvvm` or `c#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating a `ko.computed` like this

```
viewModel.rows = ko.computed(function () {
    var rows = [],
        currentRow,
        colLength = 3;
    for (var i = 0, j = this.users().length; i < j; i++) {
        if (i % colLength === 0) {
            if (currentRow) {
                rows.push(currentRow);
            }
            currentRow = [];
        }
        currentRow.push(this.users()[i]);
    }
    if (currentRow) {
        rows.push(currentRow);
    }
    return rows;
}, viewModel);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/kdLPM/4/

Additional info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7674755/17447

Answer (score 0):

Please see this below example

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=847

Hope will be helpful.