# knockout - Generate Bootstrap Styling dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am using Knockout's forech data binding to render a template. The issue is that for every three items generted using foreach binding, I want to create a new div with class row. Essentially , I want only three items to be displayed in one row. For the fourth item, noew row should be created. But the foreach data binding has been applied to the div inside the row div. How do I achieve that? Following is the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- Item #1 -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-bind="foreach:items">
      <div  data-bind="attr: {id: ID}" class="item">
        <!-- Use the below link to put HOT icon -->
        <div class="item-icon"><span>HOT</span></div>
          <!-- Item image -->
          <div class="item-image">
            <a href="single-item.html"><img data-bind="attr: {src: picture}" src="img/items/2.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"/></a>
          </div>
          <!-- Item details -->
          <div class="item-details">
            <!-- Name -->
            <h5><a data-bind="text: itemname" href="single-item.html">HTC One V</a></h5>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!-- Para. Note more than 2 lines. -->
            <!--p>Something about the product goes here. Not More than 2 lines.</p-->
            <hr />
            <!-- Price -->
            <div data-bind="text: price"  class="item-price pull-left">$360</div>
            <!-- qty -->
            <div data-bind="text: quantity" class="item-price text-center">$360</div>
            <!-- Add to cart -->
            <div class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Add to Cart</a></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function itemsKo()
  {
    var self=this;
    self.query = ko.observable();
    self.hide = ko.observable(false);
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.subcat=function()
    {

$.ajax({
                url: "/items,
                type: "get",
                success: function(data){



                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(item) {
                      item.price = "Rs" + item.price;
                     self.items.push(item);
                    });
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(window.vm.items()));
                 },
              error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   alert("failure");
                 }   
           });


    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to find a way to map your array into a structure that is rows/columns. So, an array of rows, where each row is an array of items in that row.

Here is an older answer that shows creating a computed in the VM to represent an array as a set of rows: [Knockout.js - Dynamic columns but limit to a maximum of 5 for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669946/knockout-js-dynamic-columns-but-limit-to-a-maximum-of-5-for-each-row/7674755#7674755)

Another option could be to create a custom binding that handles the plumbing of this computed for you.  The advantage is that you do not need to bloat your view model with extra code and it is reusable.  A possible implementation might look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.rows = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        var rows = ko.computed({
            read: function() {
                var index, length, row,
                    options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
                    items = ko.unwrap(options.items),
                    columns = ko.unwrap(options.columns)
                    result = [];

                for (index = 0, length = items.length; index < length; index++) {
                    if (index % columns === 0) {
                        //push the previous row, except the first time
                        if (row) {
                             result.push(row);   
                        }

                        //create an empty new row
                        row = [];
                    }

                    //add this item to the row
                    row.push(items[index]);
                }

                //push the final row  
                if (row) {
                    result.push(row);
                }

                //we know have an array of rows
                return result;
            },
            disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
        });

        //apply the real foreach binding with our rows computed
        ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, { foreach: function() { return rows; } }, context);

        //tell KO that we will handle binding the children
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Here is a quick fiddle with it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/nh6d7/

It is a computed, so the number of columns and the items can be observable and will cause it to re-render on changes. This could be a slight concern, if you are often updating the original items.